# changing value for multiple objects

Tags: scripting, objects, add-on, panel

i'm trying to make a panel grouping some button changing the display of object in the viewport (wire , subsurf optimal display, smooth shading).

It works "ok" for one object, but i'm trying to make for multiple objects at the same time.

While doing :

```
for i in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    i.modifiers['Subsurf'].show_only_control_edges = True
```

works in the python console, it doesn't in a separate script.

There's obviously something i don't see/understand...

Could someone put me on the right track please ?

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

def DisplayAllEdgesWire(self, context):
    selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

    for i in selection:

        if (self.ShowWire):
            i.show_wire = True
            i.show_all_edges = True

        else:
            i.show_wire = False
            i.show_all_edges = False


def DisplaySubdividedEdges(self, context):

    selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

    for i in selection:

        if  "Subsurf" in i.modifiers:

            if (i.ShowSubdividedEdges):
                i.modifiers["Subsurf"].show_only_control_edges = False

            else :
                i.modifiers["Subsurf"].show_only_control_edges = True

        else :
            continue

class ObjectProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        bpy.types.Object.ShowWire = BoolProperty(
            name = "show wire", 
            description = "Add the object's solid wireframe over solid drawing",
            default = False,
            update = DisplayAllEdgesWire)

        bpy.types.Object.ShowSubdividedEdges = BoolProperty(
            name = "show subdivided edges", 
            description = "Show/hide interior subdivided edges",
            default = True,
            update = DisplaySubdividedEdges)

    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        del bpy.types.Object.ShowWire
        del bpy.types.Object.ShowSubdividedEdges


class ObjectDisplayPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Object display"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):

        bpy.types.Object.ShowWire
        bpy.types.Object.ShowSubdividedEdges

        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene

        view = context.space_data
        obj = bpy.context.active_object

        col = layout.column()

        col.prop(view, "show_only_render")

        if obj.type in ["MESH","CURVE", "META", "SURFACE", "FONT"]:
            if bpy.context.mode == "OBJECT" :
                row = layout.row(align=True)
                row.operator("object.shade_smooth", text="smooth", icon="MESH_UVSPHERE")
                row.operator("object.shade_flat", text="flat", icon="MESH_ICOSPHERE")

            elif bpy.context.mode == "EDIT_MESH" :
                row = layout.row(align=True)
                row.operator("mesh.faces_shade_smooth", text="smooth", icon="MESH_UVSPHERE")
                row.operator("mesh.faces_shade_flat", text="flat", icon="MESH_ICOSPHERE")
            else :
                pass


            col = layout.column(align=True)

            row = col.row(align=True)

            row.scale_y = 2.0
            row.prop(obj, "ShowWire", icon= "MESH_GRID")

            if obj.show_wire:
                box = col.box()

                box.prop(obj, "show_all_edges", text="all edges")

                if "Subsurf" in obj.modifiers:
                    box.prop(obj, "ShowSubdividedEdges", text="subdivided edges")

                else :
                    pass

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(obj, "show_name", text="name", icon="SORTALPHA")
        row.prop(obj, "show_axis", text="axis", icon="MANIPUL")
        row.prop(obj, "show_x_ray", text="x-ray", icon="CLIPUV_DEHLT")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectDisplayPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectProperties)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectDisplayPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ObjectProperties)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Well, it seems to works will maintaining "alt" and clicking the checkbox (like a "real" blender button do).
But i would still like to know why it doesn't in my script...

Comment: The issue is with an update event on `bpy.types.Object.someboolprop` only sets that prop on the context object.  If other objects have that prop as `False` then their modifier prop is never changed (as your code stands).   If you take out that test and set `mod.pop = self.someboolprop` you'll get out of sync.  Worse would be `obj.someboolprop = self.someboolprop` as it will cause an update loop that will most likely crash blender. Reconsider using an operator instead of the update method.  That can set all selected object props  to True / False / Toggle etc.